# Logging HTTP traffic in combination with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, redirect, proxy

I'm building a crawler using Selenium and Java that crawls malicious webpages (I provide the domain names).

The start point of my crawl is a parked domain. Often these domains automatically redirect to malicious web pages. I would like to log these redirects.

I'm planning to let the crawler rotate user-agents. This means sometimes I will be crawling using firefox, other times chrome, etc. What would be the best way to log the redirects knowing that I will be using different browsers?

I will also be using proxies to make me less detectable.

Should I use Wireshark for this situation or are there better options?

Comment: Selenium doesn't explicitly provide support for network traffic; however, it does provide support for proxies. Please, take a look at `BrowserMob` proxy https://bmp.lightbody.net/

Comment: @RafałLaskowski I thought that only supported the Firefox webdriver, but I didn't look good enough.

Comment: Well, you read well. I would start from there with Firefox and get some knowledge about logging network traffic and find, what exactly do I need to perform my task.

Or you can just start with `Wireshark`. If you want to start with Wireshark and integrate it with Java you have 2 options

1. run tshark (possibly with option -V) and then parse the text output with Java
2. You can use Java libraries/bindings:
a) [jNetPcap](http://jnetpcap.com/)
b) [Jpcap](http://jpcap.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: There is one more possible option - using `Apache JMeter` as a proxy. Start `JMeter` recording and run your automation script. It might be hard to find your redirects if you have a heavy crawler. The more you crawl with `Selenium` the more traffic `JMeter` will get.

It's up to you now :)

Comment: @RafałLaskowski Thanks for the possibilities, tomorrow I'll work with BrowserMob.